# nebular with material-icon are not shown icons

Tags: angular, nebular, material-icons

I follow the documentation and configure the ligature font pack [documentation icon](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/register-icon-pack#register-icon-pack)

```
  constructor(
  private _iconLibraries: NbIconLibraries
 ) {
  this._iconLibraries.registerFontPack('material-icons', {
   ligature: true,
  });
```

in my app.module.ts I have the imports like this

```
 imports: [
  NbEvaIconsModule,
  NbIconModule,
  MatIconModule,
  ...
 ]
```

And i have this in my component:

```
 <nb-icon icon="star"></nb-icon>
 <nb-icon icon="group" pack="material-icons"></nb-icon>
 <nb-icon icon="star"></nb-icon>
 <mat-icon>group</mat-icon>
 <nb-icon icon="star"></nb-icon>
```

The "star" icons are showed without problems, the "group" in the mat-icon is showed too, but the "group" inside nb-icon is shown as "group" text, no icon.

[image]

And in the package.json i have this:

```
"@angular/material": "~13.1.0",
"@nebular/eva-icons": "9.0.0",
"@nebular/theme": "^9.0.0",
"eva-icons": "^1.1.2",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"nebular-icons": "^1.1.0",
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2554

Seems the Nebular documentation didn't document well; and has been bugged fixed as well. Just follow its example without CustomNbIconLibraries as long you running on v9 Nebular Theme.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private iconLibraries: NbIconLibraries) {
    this.registerMaterialIcons();
  }

  private registerMaterialIcons() {
    this.iconLibraries.registerFontPack("material-icons", {
      packClass: "material-icons",
      ligature: true
    });
    this.iconLibraries.setDefaultPack("material-icons");
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I almost surrender with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your index.html import

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work either.